# How to Tell That this Relation is AntiSymmetric

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

We have $A = \{1,2,3,4 \}$ and the relation $R = \{(2,1), (3,1), (3,2), (4,1), (4,2), (4,3) \}$.

My book is saying that this is antisymmetric, but I cannot figure out why. I know the definition is $\forall a \forall b(((a,b)\in R \land (b,a)\in R) \rightarrow (a=b)).$

I used the definition here and I am not getting anywhere. Does someone else have a recommendation on how to look at this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are there elements $a,b\in A$ such that both $(a,b)$ and $(b,a)$ belong to $R$? No, there aren't. So, the assertion$$(a,b)\in R\wedge(b,a)\in R\implies a=b$$is vacuously true.

Comment: I see! We are using a true value for this. So this is equvilent to saying $F \rightarrow F$ which is a true statement?

Comment: I don't see why you are saying that what you want to prove is equivalent to $F\rightarrow F$. It is equivalent to an assertion of the type $E\rightarrow F$ in which $E$ is always false, and therefore $E\rightarrow F$ is true.

Comment: My mistake. I meant to have $F$ translates to false. So false implies false is always true.

Comment: What matters here is that false implies something is always true (after all, $a$ *can* be equal to $b$).